# How can I create Stripe express accounts on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I want to create Stripe express accounts for my customers (who will receive money) on my WordPress platform. An user account will be created when the user registers on my platform. How can I do it?

I've installed two Stripe extensions to help me but none of those extensions allows account creation for customers. I've tried browsing on Stripe docs in order to write my own code. I found some examples and tried a short code for the code below after including the Stripe library folder in my theme folder.

```
require_once get_template_directory() . '/stripe-php-master/lib/Stripe.php';
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('<my_stripe_secret_api_key');

$stripe->accounts->create(['type' => 'express']);
```

I've include the short code on my customers registering page, but nothing worked as expected. I expected my code to create an express account without any information (apart of the mandatory one which is the account type) to see if that code worked but nothing happened.

Comment: *I expected my code to create an express account without any information* - there are probably minimum details which need to be provided to create an account.  This should be in the documentation.

Comment: @NigelRen the minimum information is the account type, that I provide. Thank you anyway. I added that detail in the post.

Comment: Stripe has pretty decent and clear documentation. their base API docs is [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api) and they even have a [demo](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#express-demo) for what you need. not sure what your shotcode has to do with it, but you need to run relevant stripe function call when your user successfully registers, which normally done through hooks in wordpress

Comment: @silver I found the code [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts). I read their base API about account creating.  I will look for the demo, thank you. I'm not familiar with hooks. I'll try browsing about it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just to double-check @NigelRen 's line of thought - what happens if you follow the [example in the API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create) exactly - and better yet, dump out responses and add a try/catch to see potential issues?

```php
try {
  require_once get_template_directory() . '/stripe-php-master/lib/Stripe.php';
  $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('<my_stripe_secret_api_key');

  // A. Use exact example from API Docs just to make sure we're not missing something
  $response = $stripe->accounts->create([
    'type' => 'custom',
    'country' => 'US',
    'email' => 'jenny.rosen@example.com',
    'capabilities' => [
      'card_payments' => ['requested' => true],
      'transfers' => ['requested' => true],
    ],
  ]);
  echo "Response 1: ";
  var_dump($response);

  // B. Then switch *just* the account type and confirm the difference
  $response = $stripe->accounts->create([
    'type' => 'express',
    'country' => 'US',
    'email' => 'jenny.rosen@example.com',
    'capabilities' => [
      'card_payments' => ['requested' => true],
      'transfers' => ['requested' => true],
    ],
  ]);
  echo "Response 2: ";
  var_dump($response);

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "ERROR: ";
  var_dump($e->getMessage());
  die;
}
```

2. How are you verifying?
3. What do you see in your Stripe account?
4. What do you get as the result of the API call itself - or is there an exception thrown?
5. Does the result look different from 1A. vs. 1B. above?
6. Does the result look different from when you create an account manually?

I hope that helps get you on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the account creation working for the platform. You can note some errors that I corrected. I also move stripe library folder on the server.

```php
try{
 require_once('/htdocs/wp-content/stripe-php-master/init.php');
    $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('<my_stripe_secret_api_key>');

    $account = $stripe->accounts->create([
        'type' => 'express',
        'country' => 'US',
        'email' => 'test@test.com',
        'capabilities' => [
          'card_payments' => ['requested' => true],
          'transfers' => ['requested' => true],
        ]]);
}catch(Exception $e){
   print($e->getMessage());
}
```

Thank to you all.

Comment: Please don’t use the “Post Your Answer” button to submit content which does not attempt to answer the question at the top of this page. If you want to update or clarify your question, [edit it.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77735326/edit)